# How to use MathJax in AstroJS project to typeset all \[tex\] code on page into MathML code during build

Tags: node.js, typescript, mathjax, astrojs

I have started using AstroJS as a Static Site Generator in my recent project. The main advantage of using AstroJS is the ability to run JS code in the `--- ---` code fences part of `.astro` file to produce webpages with zero JS code.

When included in websites, via a CDN using `<script>` tags, MathJax makes page longer to load, and takes long to process.

- One solution to reducing load-time is to include MathJax javascript file only on required pages using AstroJS's [Components](https://docs.astro.build/en/core-concepts/astro-components/).
- To reduce the processing time during pageload we can use MathJax's [Lazy Typesetting](https://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/output/lazy.html#lazy-typesetting-options).

Since AstroJS can run JS code during build time, I wanted to just import `tex-mml-chtml.js` file into the webpage and then execute `MathJax.typeset()`.

### Here is the code I have tried so far:

```
---
import { MathJax } from '../scripts/tex-mml-chtml.js';
MathJax.typeset();
---

<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <meta name="generator" content={Astro.generator} />
    <title>Astro</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Astro</h1>
    \[x^2+2x+15=0\]
  </body>
</html>
```

This gives me the error `"MathJax" is not exported by "src/scripts/tex-mml-chtml.js"`

***Is there a simple way in which inline TeX code like `\[x^2+2x+15=0\]` be converted into MathML code during build?***

**MathJax-Node?:**

Can [MathJax-Node](https://www.mathjax.org/#installnow) package be used for converting tex to mathml? There isn't much explanation on the [Documentation Page](https://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/server/start.html).

I have tried `npm install mathjax`, `npm install mathjax-full`, `npm install mathjax-node`. All give type errors like  `type require not found`. I don't use TypeScript in the Project as I've not really learnt TS.

Answer (score 0):

The `tex-mml-chtml.js` file doesn't have any exports, but it does create a global variable `MathJax` that you can use.  Note, however, that you don't have to call `MathJax.typeset()` itself, as `tex-mml-chtml.js` will do that automatically when the page is finished loading.

One thing to realize is that MathJax may load other files in addition to `tex-mml-chtml.js`.  For example, you need to have the font files available, so if you have just moved `tex-mml-chtml.js` to your scripts directory, that may not be enough.  Since you are importing the file rather than loading it via `<script>` tag, MathJax won't be able to figure out where those other files are located, so you might need to set the MathJax configuration to specify the `mathjax` path.  If you use `npm install mathjax`, then you would want to include everything from the `node_modules/mathjax/es5` directory.

It might be easier to just include the proper `<script>` tag in the document `<head>` so that MathJax will be able to locate its files.  In that case, you can use MathJax from a CDN rather than having your own copy (unless you need to work off line).  See the [documentation](https://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/web/start.html#using-mathjax-from-a-content-delivery-network-cdn) for details.